# How to Set a property of an Array type

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, xml-serialization

I have a SOAP Header in my application. I need to add a new value of type `item` with key  **pcimask** and value **true** to the *ClientContext*

my clientcontext looks like this when populated:

```
{EvryCardManagement.ws.card.DCSSCardCreate_V3_0.ClientContextType}
channel: "NBA"
channelField: "NBA"
credentials: "token string"
credentialsField: "string"
customerid: ""
customeridField: ""
ip: "123.456.789.123"
ipField: "123.456.789.123"
item: null
itemField: null
locale: null
localeField: null
orgid: "123456"
orgidField: "123456"
orgunit: "123456"
orgunitField: "123456"
userid: "name"
useridField: "name"
```

after the  I need to add a new element called `pcimask` with a value **true**.

**UPDATE:** in the wsdl there is an element called `item` (within the `ClientContext`), and I need to add it to the SOAP Message Headers like this: `<item key="pcimask" value="true"/>`

In the web-service WSDL the `item` that I need to set is defined like this:

```
private itemType[] itemField;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("item", IsNullable=true)]
public itemType[] item {
    get {
        return this.itemField;
        }
    set {
        this.itemField = value;
        }
    }
```

and so in my code that sets these values I have this:

```
ClientContextType clientContext = new ClientContextType();

clientContext.userid = edb_service[0].userid;

clientContext.credentials = Common.SOToken;

//clientContext.pc
clientContext.orgid = edb_service[0].orgid;
clientContext.orgunit = edb_service[0].orgunit;
clientContext.customerid = "";
clientContext.channel = edb_service[0].channel;
clientContext.ip = edb_service[0].ip;
```

and after the `ip` element I want to set the item:

```
clientContext.item = edb_service[0].pcimask;
```

but it won't compile as it's like an array or list, and I need to add a new item so it shows up in the header xml like this:

```
<item key=”pcimask” value=”true”>
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Do you mean, what do you do after changing the `ClientContextType` class?

Comment: @JohnSaunders well, in the wsdl there is an element called `item` (within the `ClientContext`), and I need to add it to the SOAP Message Headers like this: `<item key="pcimask" value="true"/>` and despite reading all over the web about Message Interceptors, and Soap Extensions, I am completely lost.

Comment: You should not have to add anything. The question should be why isn't this already in the header. Did you try setting the "item" property?

Comment: I think you're right, I will update with the WSDL definition of the `Item` which I need to set.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I have edited my question to clarify my problem, I think I am meant to add a new member to the `item` list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do something like

```
clientContext.item = new itemType[]{new itemType{key="pcimask", value="true"}};
```

`item` is an array. You have to create an array, populate it with the appropriate data, then use that array to set `item`. The above is a shortcut for doing that. Step by step:

```
itemType it = new itemType();
it.key = "pcimask";
it.value = "true";
itemType[] itArray = new itemType[];
itArray[0] = it;
clientContext.item = itArray;
```

BTW note that this has nothing to do with SOAP headers. Your problem was simply that you don't know  how to set an array.

Comment: Thankyou so much, this has taken me a long time and lot's of teeth gnashing to grasp...